# How can i store my ip as a var? (excluding non desired IP's)

Tags: batch-file

I got this code:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2* delims=:" %%i in (' ipconfig ^| find "IP" ') do set dirip=%%j
set dirip=%dirip:~1%
```

But, the dirip var, store the last IP address of 3 that i got, i want something that allow me to select wich one of all the IP's i want to store. Something like:

```
Select the IP you want:
1. 192.168.2.1
2. 169.254.75.253
3. 192.168.114.1
```

And if i press 1 and press enter for example store in dirip 192.168.2.1
Thank you. Apologize for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set n=0
for /f "tokens=1,2* delims=:" %%i in (' ipconfig ^| find "IP" ') do (
   set dirip=%%j
   set dirip=!dirip:~1!
   set /A n+=1
   set dirip[!n!]=!dirip!
   echo !n!. !dirip!
)
set /A i=n+1
:getNumber
set /P "i=Select the IP you want: "
if %i% gtr %n% goto getNumber
set dirip=!dirip[%i%]!
echo Result: %dirip%
```

Comment: Amaizing, i was searching in google for hours, and finally you solve my problem, really thank you!